# Insert text N lines before the last line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, ed

I want to insert a new line in two lines before the last line. So if my original file is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

The result should be

```
1
2
3
New line
4
5
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `ed`:

```
$ printf '$-1i\nNew line\n.\n,p\n' | ed -s file
1
2
3
New line
4
5
```

The `ed` editing script:

```
$-1i
New line
.
,p
```

This first moves to the line one line up from the end (`$-1`) and inserts (`i`) new contents above that line.  The contents inserted is ended with the single dot (it's allowed to be multiple lines).  The last `,p` displays the complete modified buffer on the terminal.

You may redirect this to a new file, or you may write it back to the original file using

```
printf '$-1i\nNew line\n.\nw\n' | ed -s file
```

(the `,p` is changed to `w`).

This latter is also how you would similarly use `ex` for this job:

```
printf '$-1i\nNew line\n.\nw\n' | ex -s file
```

`ed` and `ex` are standard line-oriented editors (as opposed to full-screen editors) that should come with your system.  Note that `-s` means different things to each, but is appropriate for both when doing batch mode editing tasks like this.

- [`ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html).  "Shell and utilities".  *Base specifications*.  IEEE 1003.1:2017.  The Open Group.
- [`ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).  "Shell and utilities".  *Base specifications*.  IEEE 1003.1:2017.  The Open Group.

Further reading:

- Dale Dougherty and Tim O'Reilly (1987). "Advanced Editing". *[Unix Text Processing](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/utp/)*. Hayden Books.

Comment: This is the best solution so far but keep in mind that it has its limitations too (dealing with huge files or inserting lines that consist of a single dot).

Answer (score 6):

It can be done by simple `head` and `tail`:

```
$ output=$(head -n -2 file ; echo 'new line' ; tail -2 file)
$ echo "$output" > file
```

As mentioned in comments , it will eat any trailing blank lines. 
So , for preserving trailing blank lines,

```
$ head -n -2 file >> file.tmp
$ echo 'new line' >> file.tmp
$ tail -2 file >> file.tmp
$ mv file.tmp file
```

or single liner

```
$ head -n -2 file >> file.tmp ; echo 'new line' >> file.tmp; tail -2 file >> file.tmp ; mv file.tmp file
```

Comment: This will eat up any trailing blank lines in the input file.

Comment: @don_crissti Why do the trailing blank lines get eaten? The command within `$(...)` works fine by itself, so is it the assignment?

Comment: @Sparhawk - it's the command substitution: [_The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution \[...\] with the standard output of the command, removing sequences of one or more newlines at the end of the substitution._](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03)

Comment: I have updated answer, now I am using redirection instead of command substitution and off-course it is preserving trailing blank lines

Comment: simple and easy to understand

Comment: Errr, at least on a Mac, this will explode (and eat your file). `head -n -2` produces a `head: illegal line count -- -2` (Mac doesn't ship with an offset flag). `head -n $(( $(wc -l < $FILE) - 2 )) $FILE will get you everything UP TO the second to last line. `tail -2 $FILE` will get you the last 2. SOooOOoo... on a MAC, at least, your one-liner would look something like `head -n $(( $(wc -l < "$FILE") - $END_LNS )) "$FILE" >> "$FILE.tmp" && echo "<string name=\"ServerIP\">https://$(whatismyip):5000</string>" >> "$FILE.tmp" && tail -$END_LNS "$FILE" >> "$FILE.tmp" && mv "$FILE.tmp" "$FILE"`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use GNU `sed` too:

```
sed -zE 's/(\n[^\n]*){3}$/\nNew-line&/' infile
```

Insert a line `New-line` in third last line of the file (Insert a line two lines before the last line).

This `(\n[^\n]*){3}$` matches `\n`ewline followed by anything but not a `\n`ewline and maximum 3 times from end of the file where `-z` option casing *sed* to read a file as a single line (separate lines by NUL characters). So it will match below only (between asterisks I highlighted):

```
3*\n
4\n
5\n*
```

Portability, you would use:

```
sed -e ':t;N;$!bt; s/\(\n[^\n]*\)\{2\}$/\nNew-line&/' infile
```

if still your `sed` cannot handle a `\n`ewline in replacement part, you can have actual newline or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> which will print `^M` control characters of enter key:

```
sed -e ':t;N;$!bt; s/\(\n[^\n]*\)\{2\}$/\
New-line&/' infile
```

#### How it works

The `N` append each line *sed* read to the pattern space followed by a new line added until all lines read. The `:t` defines a label and `$!bt` telling *sed* jump to the label called `t` as long as it's not end of the file.

Comment: I suspect this will get really slow with a huge input file and a large no. of lines that follow the insertion... Also, just like Rakesh's solution, this requires sanitizing  `NEW_LINE` before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` could help too.

```
awk -v line=$(wc -l < Input_file) -v val="new_line" 'FNR==(line-1){print val} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should be quite robust against contents of the inserted line, but requires the file to be scanned twice (`wc` for the first pass).

```
sed "$(($(wc -l < yourfile)-$N))a"'new line' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '
   1N
   $!{N;P;D;}
   H;g;s/^/NEW_LINE/
' input-data.txt
```

### How it works

- At all times maintain two ines in the pattern space.
- Print the first of the two lines in the pattern space, chop it off, and read and append the next.
- Rinse...Lather...Repeat so long as the last line has not been read into the pattern space.
- At which point, we insert a newline (\n) at the beginning and then put the required string there.
- This is POSIX-ly `sed`

Answer (score 0):

```
tac input.txt | sed '2 a New line' | tac
```

**Explanation**

- `tac` - prints lines in reverse, so the last line becomes the first, the `last - 1` line becomes the second, etc.
- `sed '2 a New line` - append `New line` after the second line.
- `tac` - reverses lines again.

**Testing**

```
$ tac <(seq 1 5) | sed '2 a New line' | tac
1
2
3
New line
4
5
```