# Append string to the end of the penultimate line of a file

Tags: text-processing, string

I want to append / concatenate a text in one line before the last line. So if my original file is:

```
1 sometext
2 sometext
3 sometext
4 sometext
5 sometext
```

my new file is

```
1 sometext
2 sometext
3 sometext
4 sometext newtext
5 sometext
```

I know already about solution on how to insert [newlines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443850/insert-text-n-lines-before-the-last-line) but this is a slightly different problem as I do not want a new line inserted and want concatenation of text instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the file line-by-line, add the text to the second line, and reverse the file again:

```
tac file | sed '2s/$/ newtext/' | tac
```

Comment: This solution worked for me and looks relatively simple.

Answer (score 3):

*vim* understands an address like `$-1`:

```
ex -sc '$-1s/$/ newtext/' +wq file
```

`ex` same as `vim -e`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR>1{printf "%s%s", ors, prev; ors=ORS} {prev=$0} END{print OFS "newtext" ORS prev}' file
1 sometext
2 sometext
3 sometext
4 sometext newtext
5 sometext
```

Answer (score 1):

```
line=$(awk 'END{print NR-1}' filename)
awk -v line="$line" 'NR==line{$0=$0" newtext"}1' filename
```

output

```
1 sometext
2 sometext
3 sometext
4 sometext newtext
5 sometext
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the address via counting lines and arithmetic:

```
sed "$(wc -l infile | awk '{print $1-1}')s/$/ newtext/" infile
```

Comment: You could replace `wc -l infile | awk '{print $1-1}'` with `awk 'END{print NR-1}' infile`.

Comment: Or even do ``sed "$(($(wc -l < infile)-1))s/$/ newtext/" infile``.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @txt=lines; my $kmax=@txt.elems; for @txt.kv -> $k,$v {$k == ($kmax-2) ?? put( $v, " newtext") !! put($v) };' sometext.txt
```

OR

```perl
~$ raku -e '.put for "sometext.txt".IO.lines[0..*-3]; put($_, " newtext") for "sometext.txt".IO.lines[*-2]; .put for "sometext.txt".IO.lines[*-1];'
```

Sample Input:

```
1 sometext
2 sometext
3 sometext
4 sometext
5 sometext
```

Sample Output (for both code examples):

```
1 sometext
2 sometext
3 sometext
4 sometext newtext
5 sometext
```

The above two Raku code examples represent a starting point. I'm certain these can be improved. The first example using `kv` key-value numbering is adapted (generally) from [this SO answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/683272/227738), while the second example is adapted (generally) from [this Perl(5)doc FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5#How-do-I-change,-delete,-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file,-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file?).

Example 1: Briefly, `lines` are read in and stored in the `@txt` array. The number of lines is obtained using `elems` and assigned to the `$kmax` (key-maximum) scalar. The `@txt` array is converted to `kv` key-value and read into a `for` loop, which implements a `condition ?? $true !! $false` ternary conditional operator. See [this link for info on the Raku ternary](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-operator_ternary). Text is appended to the appropriate `$k == ($kmax-2)` (penultimate) line using said ternary operator.

Example 2: This is really adapted straight from the Perl5 code. The difference is that Raku's `lines` routine handles opening/closing filehandles, and is lazy as well. The Raku code simply implements three succesive `put` ("print-using-\n-terminator") statements, however a difference (compared to Perl5) is that file-lines are read in as `IO` objects, and not off of the (presumably `bash`) command line.

Example 2 (cont'd): The second (middle) statement appends `" newtext"` to the `$_` topic variable (containing line-text), while the first and third statements prints the before/after text verbatim. Of course, output can be redirected to a file instead of outputting to the terminal, e.g. by appending  `> new_sometext.txt` to the end of the Example 2 code above.

Looking at the [the Perl(5)doc FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5#How-do-I-change,-delete,-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file,-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file?), we see a number of modules used to solve this problem in Perl5. Raku (née Perl6) has cognate modules...meaning more concise/efficient solutions *may be* available in Raku using modules.

Finally, if you run into problems fitting the file into memory, and/or you prefer getting the # of lines separately, you can do that via the Raku one-liner:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'state $i; $i++; END put $i-1;' sometext.txt
4
```

Then simply run the code below, using the computed (penultimate) line-number `3`:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'if $++ == 3 { say($_, " newtext") } else { say($_) };' sometext.txt
1 sometext
2 sometext
3 sometext
4 sometext newtext
5 sometext
```